# Не открываются формы при нажатии кнопки

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть метод для события нажатия кнопки 'button_add'. При нажатии должна открываться одна из дополнительных форм. Какая именно - зависит от выбранного варианта в comboBox1. Но этого не происходит, когда я сделал форму для первого варианта. Она работала. Но как добавил if всё сломалось. Как починить?
Сам метод:

```
private void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        AddSellForms addSellForms = new AddSellForms();
        addSellForms.Show();
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        AddEmpForm addEmpForm = new AddEmpForm();
        addEmpForm.Show();
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        AddTovForm addTovForm = new AddTovForm();
        addTovForm.Show();

    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {
        AddDolzhForm addDolzhForm = new AddDolzhForm();
        addDolzhForm.Show();
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 4)
    {
        AddOtdelForm addOtdelForm = new AddOtdelForm();
        addOtdelForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Пытался убирать IF, возвращать начальный вариант для первой формы. Она тоже не открылась.

Comment: В таких случаях надо смотреть не на "не открывается", а на отладку, самый главный инструмент программиста. Вот поставьте точку остановки в самое начало, запустите проект, нажмите на кнопку, вам IDE сделает паузу в этом месте, если не сделало - значит в метод вовсе не заходит, сразу вопрос "почему?", идете и смотрите, а привязан обработчик вообще к кнопке? Ну а если заходит, то жмете F10 или F11 (с заходом в метод), и так бежите по коду, изучая что лежит в тех или иных переменных и соответствует-ли это с вашими ожиданиями. И да, много if/else плохо, не лучшая идея, можно очень сильно упростить.

Comment: Просто для оптимизации кода и не быть YandereDev'ом, используйте switch(comboBox1.SelectedIndex){ case 1: break; }

Comment: Слишком мало информации для решения, может у вас отвязался хандлер?